# Automation API to get Element Type list and Fields available for particular Element Type

Tags: c#, api, enterprise-architect

I have couple of questions regarding Sparx EA automation API in C#.

1) How can I get the list of all Types available. For example : Feature, Requirement, Action etc.

2) Is it possible to get the fields applicable to particular type?  For example When I wanted to create element of type **Action**, **Priority** field is not available for that type. But when I am creating the element of Type **Feature**, **Priority** field is there in the screen.
Now, I want to create element of different type using API. So, I need a list of all available fields for particular type. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use Repository.GetReferenceList to get a list of available
   element types
2. No that info is not available.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/modeling_languages/elements_used_in_toolboxes.html) is a list of elements used in toolbox.
2. As far as I know, there is no option.